# Getting error : LOGBACK: No context given for net.logstash.logback.LogstashFormatter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logstash, logback

I am trying to print a log in the SpringBoot Application using Logback and the following configuration, but the logs are not printing.
Spring-boot version 2.7.2 and Java version 17 are being used.

In pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
    <version>6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

In logback-spring.xml, I have given the property that is being referenced from the application.yml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <springProperty scope="context" name="APP_NAME" source="spring.application.name"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_ROOT_PATH" source="log.root.path"/>
    <property name="HOME_LOG" value="${LOG_ROOT_PATH}/logs/${APP_NAME}/${APP_NAME}.json"/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME_LOG}</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ROOT_PATH}/logs/${APP_NAME}/archived/${APP_NAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.json</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each archived file, size max 10MB -->
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <totalSizeCap>2GB</totalSizeCap>
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <providers>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                            "timestamp": "%d{ISO8601}",
                            "trace": "%X{traceId:-}",
                            "span": "%X{spanId:-}",
                            "level": "%level",
                            "logger": "%logger",
                            "thread": "%thread",
                            "application": "${APP_NAME}",
                            "message": "%msg"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>
            </providers>
    </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.til" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Please help.
Thanks